# How can I create a cluster with EMR-4.1.0 with Spark 1.5.0 Step with Python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr

I'm moving from **Python Pandas** to **Spark**.

I have a Python script on S3,

How can I **create a cluster** with `aws emr create-cluster` to run this Python script as step, like I do with Pig or Hive?

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
aws emr create-cluster \
--name added_step_spark \
--release-label emr-4.1.0 \
--applications Name=Spark \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey \
--instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 \
--steps Type=Spark,Name=MyStep,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn-cluster,s3://my-bucket/scripts/my_scripts.py] \
--use-default-roles
```